# Is there any reliable free/open source tool for structured mesh smoothing?

Tags: mesh-generation, grid, smoothing

I have been using Pointwise for grid generation and found the quality of smoothed grids to be stunning.

I am not aware of any free/open source alteranative that offers the same capabilities for structured grids (I am not interested in unstructured meshes).

I am aware of Meshlab but never used it (it doesn't even have undo functionality!).

Here is what I mean by smoothing (Using the elliptic solver to enhance the mesh quality): See the video starting from 8:19 : https://youtu.be/ED3J8SO7kOg?t=498

Could you please suggest any candidate free/open source software/libraries for that purpose?

Comment: What "smoothed grids" are? Could you describe it?

Comment: You should define smoothed grid to have an answer, in the documentation I find this: https://www.pointwise.com/doc/user-manual/edit/smooth.html. Is  it what you mean?

Comment: Gmsh seems to have a smoothing algorithm but I can't find an example for it. Maybe asking their mailing list might help.